# MSB4057: The target "pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder" does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, azure, github

New developer here. I pushed my code to GitHub and then tried to build and deploy it but received this error.

Error:

```
D:\a\Deploy\Deploy\SimpleInventory\SimpleInventory.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder" does not exist in the project.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the below workarounds to resolve this issue:

- Check whether your application .csproj file has the multiple lines for building like below:

```xml
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v.*.*\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(Solutions.VSVersion)' == '*.*'" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v*.*\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(Solutions.VSVersion)' == '*.*'" />
```

If you have found the multiple lines then try to remove `condition` from above lines as shown below:

```xml
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v.*.*\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Or alternatively,

Go to this file location `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets file`

> *C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v.*\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets*

and include the below code to your MSBuild/.csproj file,

```xml
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v.*\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that if you've recently (year 2022 >) encountered an issue on GitHub, specifically with a web forms project with multiple class libraries, a solution is available. Currently, the yml file created for you by Azure is built using VS 2022 Enterprise MSBuild on GitHub. As a result, the import statements mentioned earlier by RKM are no longer relevant. To get this working do the following:

In your startup project .csproj file ensure you have the following import:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

In every class library .csproj file add the following import:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets')" />
```

--

Update:

I would like to share an important discovery regarding my implementation. Although the solution I provided runs successfully on GitHub, it produces an artifact that belongs to only one out of seven projects in my solution. To resolve this issue, I used the following MSBuild command:

```
msbuild /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="\published\" /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True
```